# Cannot Import Wordpress Website to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, web

Here is my error:
`SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `nicolebrem1`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes` (
  `recipe_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `recipe_title` text,
  `recipe_image` text,
  `summary` text,
  `rating` text,
  `prep_time` text,
  `cook_time` text,
  `total_time` text,
  `yield` text,
  `serving_size` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `calories` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `fat` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ingredients` text,
  `instructions` text,
  `notes` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set Auto increment column as Primary key as the error message says:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes` (
  `recipe_id` bigint(20) unsigned PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `recipe_title` text,
  `recipe_image` text,
  `summary` text,
  `rating` text,
  `prep_time` text,
  `cook_time` text,
  `total_time` text,
  `yield` text,
  `serving_size` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `calories` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `fat` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ingredients` text,
  `instructions` text,
  `notes` text,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping man but I've got a new error.
SQL query:

Dumping data for table `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes`


INSERT INTO `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes` (`recipe_id`, `post_id`, `recipe_title`, `recipe_image`, `summary`, `rating`, `prep_time`, `cook_time`, `total_time`, `yield`, `serving_size`, `calories`, `fat`, `ingredients`, `instructions`, `notes`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 21, 'Super nutty.. code goes on


#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @waitwhat It works for me , [check fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=def9810a6616d4795251b1f68f462c01) . what's the error message you are getting?

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' .. I have lines of code like this 
INSERT INTO `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes` (`recipe_id`, `post_id`, `recipe_title`, `recipe_image`, `summary`, `rating`, `prep_time`, `cook_time`, `total_time`, `yield`, `serving_size`, `calories`, `fat`, `ingredients`, `instructions`, `notes`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 21, 'Supe......code goes on

Comment: you are trying to insert duplicate value into primary key ( recipe_id) , PK should be unique

Comment: it's not me. i just exported this one from the db. How do I fix it?

Comment: here is preview of the first line of codes
https://ctrlv.link/5New

Comment: is the table already created ? maybe drop it if it already exists

Comment: Yes definitely. Here ya go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tCNkQBzxgTHNQFZkT0dR2Q6NoLFIdvWJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so that's the problem , table already exists and It has already data in it with recipe_id =1 and now you are trying to insert recipe_id =1 while its duplicate and it's not allowed

Comment: Okay. So what do you mean? I delete the _INSERT INTO_ codes?

Comment: no empty the table. use this ommand before running your script : `delete from `wp_amd_zlrecipe_recipes`  where  `recipe_id`  in ( 1,2 ,3)` -- which will delete these rows from table.

Comment: Okay, so I'm a little inexperienced here. How do I run the script? What software do I use?

Comment: wherever you are running your current script

Comment: Is the problem with exporting of the db? Because when I exported it in myphp I used minimal option.

Comment: oh probably you exported that script and running it on the same database, Is that possible?

Comment: i dont.. know? currently my new db is up. but i can still log on to my backed up db and i can still log in my phpadmin.

Comment: I suppose you want it to be executed against a new empty database